# Convert char to uint8_t array with a specific format in C

Tags: c, parsing, char, hex

I want to convert a `char` into a specific format.

```
char *hexstring = "e0606664387d";
```

should look like:

```
uint8_t mac[] = { 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d };
```

Something like:

```
uint8_t mac[12];
char *hexstring = "e0606664387d";
mac_filter[0] = "{ ";

int i;
for (i = 0; i < (strlen(hexstring) / 2); i++) {
    sscanf(hexstring + 2*i, "%02x ", &mac[i]);
    if (i < (strlen(hexstring) / 2) - 1){
        mac[i] = printf("0x%02x, ", mac[i]);
    }
    else{
        mac[i] = printf("0x%02x", mac[i]);
    }
}

mac[i + 1] = printf(" }");
```

But, of course, this won't work!

Comment: Don't use `sscanf` but extract the individual hexadecimals strings ("e0", "60", "66" etc.)  and transform them using [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/). Should me no more than 8 lines of code.

Comment: And just noticed: using `printf` is really not the thing you need here.

Comment: Should the target string really be in string format too? Because `uint8_t` rather suggests it should be in raw data format? Why would you use `uint8_t` if it is a string?

Comment: It isn't clear if you want a string containing `uint8_t mac[] = { 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d };` in your program, which can presumably be printed out, or whether you want an array in your program containing the 6 bytes 0x0E, … 0x7D.  If you want the string, your `mac` array isn't big enough (and it isn't clear what `mac_filter` is).  If you want the array, the `mac[i+1] = printf(" }");` line is a peculiar way of assigning 2 to `mac[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char *hexstring = "e0606664387d";
uint8_t mac[8];

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; hexstring[i] != 0; i++)
  {
    char byte[3];
    strncpy(byte, &hexstring[i * 2], 2);  // copy 2 characters
    byte[2] = 0;                          // put NUL string terminator
    mac[i] = strtol(byte, NULL, 16);      // convert string such as "e0" to 0xe0
  }

  // display the mac array

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mac)/sizeof(mac[0]); i++)
  {
    printf("%02x\n", mac[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: he wants to have a MAC as a string as well :)

Comment: @PeterJ yes, maybe the questiuon wasn't quite clear.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I work with an uint8_t like this ``uint8_t mac[] = { 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d }``. But now (because of reasons) this mac is a String in this format ``e0606664387d``. This String should be converted into ``uint8_t mac[] = { 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d }`` so i can work with it again in my code. It has to be in this format as ``unint8_t``.

Comment: @Michael Walz - IMO J.Doe  should buy a book first, read it and then start asking :)

Comment: @J.Doe so the program in my answer should be what you want. Please confirm by accepting the answer or post another comment explaining what you want.

Comment: @J.Doe or please confirm that the quotes (`"`) are misplaced in your question and that you actually wanted to write `uint8_t mac[] = { 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d };` instead of `uint8_t mac[] = "{ 0xe0, 0x60, 0x66, 0x64, 0x38, 0x7d }";`

Comment: Tried your script, it's working perfectly and is exactly what i was looking for!